# How will I compare today's date with database date in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<li ng-repeat="iteration over values" ng-show="compare date with today's date">
//code for display
</li>
```

How can I compare the date with the today's date?

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Because if you are after simple list filtering it's better to use angular filters or to filter the list in the controller after you get it from backend than to do this using the ng-show. It would be much more performant.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="iteration over values" ng-if="compareDate(iteration)">
  //code for display
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.compareDate = function (val) {
  // your code here
  return true or false
}
```

Comment: Please offer some explanation, and fix indentation for your code, to improve the quality of your answer. See here for help on [Writing a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
 <li ng-repeat="iteration over values" ng-show="showEvents(dt,today )">
    //code for display
    </li>

$scope.showEvents=function(dt,today){
      var datea = moment(dt);
      var dateb = moment(today);
      return datea.diff(dateb, 'days') >= 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `momentjs` then Nikita's answer will work.

If you want to compare in core js then:-

```
<li ng-repeat="iteration over values" ng-show="dateCompare(dt)">
    //code for display
 </li>

$scope.dateCompare = function(dt){
      var otherdate = new Date(dt);
      var today = new Date();
      return otherdate.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() && otherdate.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && otherdate.getDate() === today.getDate();
}
```